# Is It OK to Rewrite Email Addresses Intended for Remote Delivery to Use CNames?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, cname-record, mx-record

I've discovered that a remote site is rewriting email intended for our machines to use the CName of the machine that the mail was addressed to (e.g. mail@virtual.virtualdomain.com becomes mail@cname.maindomain.com). Is this correct behavior?

If so, can this be avoided by also adding an MX record or something else?

Comment: Can you clarify the current behavior? When emails are addressed, people send them to an alias and then they are redirected to the real address?

Comment: Mail is addressed to user@virtualmachine.virtualdomain.com. This is a CName for realmachine.realdomain.com. Most mailers do not muck with the address, but instead hand off the mail to realmachine with the virtualmachine.virtualdomain.com address intact. Our local machine then correctly sorts things out. However I've discovered one remote machine that rewrites the internal address of the mail from user@virtualmachine.virtualdomain.com to user@realmachine.realdomain.com before handing it to realmachine. Trying to find out if I should be accounting for this sort of thing or if it's wrong.

Comment: Which header does it modify?

Comment: I see the change in the Received: headers. The Received: header for the user's machine says that it's delivery for <user@virtualmachine.virtualdomain.com> and then when the user's ISP hands it off to my realmachine, that Received header says that its For <user@realmachine.realdomain.com>. The "To:" address still seems to be virtualmachine by the time I see it, but  "Delivered-To:" and (oddly) "X-Original-To:" both reflect realmachine. My own maillogs also exclusively show the realmachine address  (and the mail is clearly delivered as if it were addressed to realmachine).

Comment: It sounds like the only headers affected are headers whose semantics aren't well-defined anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, this behavior is wrong.. but enforcing RFC standards in SMTP is hopeless. To quote [RFC 5321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt):

> The lookup first attempts to locate an MX record associated with the name.  If a CNAME record is found, the resulting name is processed **as if it were the initial name**.

But, the sendmail MTA rewrites the recipient address by default, in violation of the RFC.  The `nocanonify` feature, or the `DontExpandCnames` option, fix this.. but when you don't have control over the server that's messing with things, all you can do is work around it.

The RFC's phrasing was originally in [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), from 2001, but hilariously, the current sendmail documentation on `DontExpandCnames` ***to this day*** says, [quote](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/tweaking_config.html):

> If set, $[ ... $] lookups that do DNS based lookups do not expand CNAME records. This currently violates the published standards, but the IETF seems to be moving toward legalizing this.